# Adding arrow to a line or div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div and using that as an arrow. I was able to generate the div but needs to attach a arrow to its top.

```css
div {
  width: 5px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: red;
  /* Rotate div */
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div>
```

jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4j8n45zz/4/

Comment: Check out http://www.cssarrowplease.com to generate the css arrow you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create this with `:after` pseudo element and just add triangle at top.

```css
div {
  width: 5px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: red;
  /* Rotate div */
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
  border-width: 0 10px 20px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```